# Fixed header in CSS for conditional scroll down?

Tags: css

I want to make a header div (like a banner) fixed only when the header is trying to go out of the screen as the user scrolls down. Is it possible to do without using JS? For an example in Facebook timeline, if we scroll down a banner floats up as soon as the page's header goes out of the screen. My question is, is it possible to do with only CSS?

In case it is not clear enough, I want to know whether a style "position: fixed" can be applied conditionally like when 80px of the page is scrolled.

Comment: CSS isn't conditional. To my knowledge this is only doable with JS.

Comment: I agree with Rick. Use Jquery for simplicity.

Comment: You cannot do this without a little bit of js to apply the new fixed position class to the banner / bar. I wouldn't use jQuery *just* to apply this class and do the measurements.. that would be overkill.

Comment: With that said: here is the jQuery demo http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/VZfXE/3/ and if jsFiddle ever stops being stupid I'll update with a vanilla demo.

Comment: This is doable with CSS.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Yes.** You can do it with just CSS. This is done by having a normal scrolling header, placed above a fixed one, which shows up only after the normal one scrolls up above it. This is kind of how http://techcrunch.com is doing it.

***Update [10/31/2013]** - Techcrunch changed their UI recently so you cannot see this there anymore!*

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WDnyb/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="outer">
    <span class="banner">LOGO</span>
    <div class="header">Header</div>
</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
}
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}
.outer .header {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    top: auto;
}
.content {
    height: 1500px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: nice, I was unaware of this technique. +1

Comment: you, Mr. @techfoobar, are super awesome! I was having a hunch that I could do something in CSS! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: One problem with this approach is that the `.outer` can obscure only _part of_ the `.header`. With big headers or small scroll increments, you can easily see both headers.

Comment: Cool approach :), too bad you have to have the header twice

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. The content of each header ends up "overlapping" and you get a double effect. Not very clean.

Comment: I'm with @KevinCantwell, not completely clean and seemless.. If you could have the fixed "Header" text in front of the other one, it would be awesome because you wouldn't see the other one sliding up..

Answer (score 7):

This can now be done properly and without javascript with `position: sticky`.

Refer to https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/ for examples.

warning: At the moment of writing, it is not supported on IE11, opera mini, <s>and android's stock browser</s>: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible using css. You can do using JavaScript or jQuery. Because it need some conditions.

Comment: Upvoted for the simple reason that the accepted answer is not correct. You do need javascript for a clean implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Html----included my content within

   <header1>
       ..............
  </header1> 

 JS

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var $header1 = $("header1"),
    $clone = $header1.before($header1.clone().addClass("clone"));

     $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var fromTop = $("body").scrollTop();
    $('body').toggleClass("down", (fromTop > 200));
 });
 });
</script>
```

i have used above script to make a header fixed,its working fine in googlechrome not in firefox.....