# Making a division fixed after scrolling beyond it

Tags: jquery, html, css, header, scroll

I have a header which comes after a div of `700 px`. So i want that header to become fixed after i scroll `700 px`.

This is what I have done.

```
<div id="header" class="header">......</div>
```

the `fixed class` is added by jquery and `header class` is removed.

```
.fixed{
    position:fixed;
    top:22px; 
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and I am doing this in `jquery`

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $('body').scrollTop() > 700){
        $('#header').addClass('fixed');
        $('#header').removeClass('header');
    } else {
        $('.header').removeClass('fixed');
        $('#header').addClass('header');
    } 
});
```

someone please help me. and please tell me from scratch. Tell me what `jquery` lib do i need to include and it will be better if the code is also provided because i am very new to `jquery`.

Comment: Maybe you can try the non-JS approach to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14550739/921204

Comment: Well, I suited your needs I believe. Hopefully my answer helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use CSS and jQuery

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/74wPn/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">Hello Title</div>
<div id="navBar">Navigation!</div>

<div class="filler"></div>
```

Basic markup. Nothing special here:

**CSS:**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#header {
    background:#CCC;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
}
#navBar {
    background:#AAA;
    width:100%;        
}
.sticky {  
    position: fixed;  
    width: 100%;  
    left: 0;  
    top: 0;  
    z-index: 100;  
    border-top: 0;  
}  

.filler {
    height:1000px;
}
```

Notice our `sticky` class. That does all the magic (other than `JS` figuring out how high we've scrolled.)

**jQuery/Javascript:**

```
$(function() {  
    var navTop = $('#navBar').offset().top;  

    var stickyNav = function(){  
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

        if (scrollTop > navTop) {   
            $('#navBar').addClass('sticky');  
        } else {  
            $('#navBar').removeClass('sticky');   
        }  
    };  

    stickyNav();  

    $(window).scroll(function() {  
        stickyNav();  
    });  
});
```

Just use positioning from initial page load (**ie navTop**) to evaluate how far we need to go and cache it in a variable so we're not loading it constantly. Then just make a function to run every time the window scrolls and on page load.

**Let me know if you would like further explanation.**

Comment: I have to say, I like this concept, and despite just developing it, I'm totally going to use it in a current project I have going on. Look, we helped each other :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use #header instead of.header

```
else {
        $('#header').removeClass('fixed');
        $('#header').addClass('header');
    } 


You can include jquery in jsp like this..
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you will be able to do this with pure CSS using `position: sticky`, unfortunately it is [not widely supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky).

You might want to checkout the [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin. Among other things, it makes doing [sticky elements](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) easy.