# Is there a way to do a sticky header for a table using CSS only

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, sticky

I have a simple table of airport data:

```
<table cellspacing="0">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Flight number</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Plane</th>
            <th>Airport</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Status</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Take off</td>
            <td>UN 35</td>
            <td>UtAir</td>
            <td>SuperJet 100</td>
            <td>Lisboa</td>
            <td>20:54</td>
            <td>Delayed</td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td>Take off</td>
            <td>UN 45</td>
            <td>UtAir</td>
            <td>SuperJet 100</td>
            <td>Paris</td>
            <td>19:40</td>
            <td>Cancelled</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Take off</td>
            <td>UN 5</td>
            <td>UtAir</td>
            <td>SuperJet 100</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21:10</td>
            <td>Boarding</td>
        </tr>
```

The number of rows is dynamic, and one instance of the table has a lot of rows, requiring the user to scroll down the page. Is there a way to fix the `thead` part of the table to the top of the screen using css only? Perhaps a solution similar to [this one: using two blocks to look like it's sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550397/fixed-header-in-css-for-conditional-scroll-down), but for `thead`?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you mean table as in `<table>` or let's say a div-based one? Can you re-word your question?

Comment: I mean <table>, english is not my native. Well, i have tried some ways which make the <table> <tbody> scrollable, but that's not what i need, i have a big <table> which goes to the bottom of the page, and i need to stick it's head, while scroll, but i want to know is it real to do it only in css

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that in pure CSS. You could use something similar to that: [Fixed header in CSS for conditional scroll down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550397/fixed-header-in-css-for-conditional-scroll-down) for a table based on `div`s but it would require your page to be simple enough to hack it in.

Comment: Yeah, i've read about it, and i think it could be some trick just like this, but tables behaviour different, and this solution might have some differences, but i don't understand which ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you want only CSS, but honestly the easiest way about this I would say would just to implement a little jQuery and use something like [floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/)

It allows you to do it either way(scrolling table or window) and just needs a little bit of JS on the page.

```
$('table').floatThead({
    scrollingTop: pageTop,
    useAbsolutePositioning: true //the default value
});
```

Another good example that I really like is found on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jgx/pen/wiIGc)

Comment: Thanks, but i've already used this solution, i need one another

Answer (score 0):

```
Css styles: 

.tablesorter th {
    color: transparent;
    height: 0 !important;
    line-height: 0;
}

.tablesorter th div {
    color: black;
    background-color: #d5e9fd;
    font-size: 9pt;
    line-height: normal;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 5px !important;
}
 .tblprogressbar {
        color: darkblue;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration-color:red;
        height: 10px;
        width: 0;
        background-color: green;    
        border-radius: 1px; 
    } 


html#:
<div style="border-color:black; width: 100%; padding-top: 20px; position: relative;" class="ui-jqgrid-bdiv bgD5E9FD">
        <div style="height: 150px; overflow-y:auto;">
            <table id="ConnSortTable" class="ui-jqgrid-htable ui-common-table mt tablesorter" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
                <thead class="bgD5E9FD fcBlack f_9">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="display: none;">
                            <span><b>ID</b></span>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div><b>Carrier</b></div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div><b>Flight</b></div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div ><b>Origin</b></div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div><b>Gate</b></div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div ><b>ETA</b></div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div><b>Status</b></div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div><b>Pax</b></div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tBodyConnection" class="bg336699 fcWhite f_9"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```