# How to make the middle element stick when scrolled down

Tags: css

There are 3 elements in My HTML, like

```
<div id="summary"></div>
<div id="header"></div>
<ul id="scroll-list"></ul>
```

how could i write my css to make sure when i scroll-down the whole page, `summary` will scroll up, when `summary` disappear, `header` will stick on the top?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the [Bootstrap Affix](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp)?

Comment: Given your tags, you might want to look at [Fixed header in CSS for conditional scroll down?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14550739/7155825).

It has some duplicate HTML, and you might see some artifacts though...

Comment: Javascript would be the only "clean" solution in my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jQuery` and calculate the `height` of previous `div` or you could use `CSS` [`position:sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) as below,

> Sticky positioning is a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning.  The
>   element is treated as relative positioned until it crosses a specified
>   threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed positioned.
>
> You must specify a threshold with at least one of top, right, bottom,
>   or left for sticky positioning to behave as expected.

```css
#summary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #fcc;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}

#scroll-list {
  height: 800px;
  background: #cc1;
}
```

```html
<div id="summary">Summary</div>
<div id="header">Header</div>
<ul id="scroll-list"></ul>
```

Update -

Position:sticky is in development stage for Edge and not supported by IE, but you could check for compatibility with browser on caniuse.com.

Comment: You should point out that sticky positioning is an experimental technology and has no support in ie, unknown support in edge (it may be in development) and may need browser prefixes for other browsers

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and the useful website.

Comment: Welcome @RyanYan :-)