# Javascript is not removing class

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with my JS code. It does add class, but it does not remove it on if else statement.

```
window.onscroll = function(){stickyNav()}

function stickyNav(){
  var navbar = document.getElementById("navBarWrapper");
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
  if(window.pageYOffset >= sticky){
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  }else{
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: [Please add your code as text to your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: There is a better way to do it using [position: sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44042669/754119)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the "sticky" navbar is positioned at the top of the page. If that is the case, `navbar.offsetTop` is always 0 as long as it is sticky, and therefore the `if` condition is always true (as the pages offest can't be negative), therefore the sticky class will never get removed.

Comment: It is not on top. It has a small header that is on top and then the navbar.

Comment: @marko1996djuric doesn't matter, the principle is the same